# Finding and sorting unique file names regardless of parent folder name

Tags: linux, bash

So imagine I have a directory structure like this:

```
~/Parent
├── A
|   ├── a.txt
|   ├── b.txt
|   └── b.tar
├── B
|   ├── b.txt
|   ├── c.txt
|   └── c.tar
└── C
    ├── c.txt
    ├── d.txt
    └── d.tar
```

If i run the command:

```
find ~/Parent -name *.txt | sort -f
```

I get the result:

```
~/Parent/A/a.txt
~/Parent/A/b.txt
~/Parent/B/b.txt
~/Parent/B/c.txt
~/Parent/C/c.txt
~/Parent/C/d.txt
```

as you would expect, but the result that I would like to get to is:

```
~/Parent/A/a.txt
~/Parent/A/b.txt
~/Parent/B/c.txt
~/Parent/C/d.txt
```

is there a way to tell uniq or another bash utility to get only the unique filenames and ignore the folder names or a way to tell bash to give you only the first occurence of a filename in a sorted list?

**EDIT:**
Some clarification may be in order.  I need to handle a more complex system than the original example showed:

```
~/Parent
├── A
|   ├── 45
|   |    └── Folder1
|   |         ├── a.txt
|   |         └── a.tar
|   └── 46
|        └── Folder1
|             ├── a.txt
|             └── a.tar     
├── B
|   ├── 12
|   |    └── Folder1
|   |         ├── b.txt
|   |         └── b.tar
|   └── 13
|        └── Folder1
|             ├── b.txt
|             └── b.tar   
└── C
    ├── 99
    |    └── Folder1
    |         ├── c.txt
    |         └── c.tar
    └── 100
         └── Folder1
              ├── c.txt
              └── c.tar
```

What I want is:

```
~/Parent/A/46/Folder1/a.txt
~/Parent/B/13/Folder1/b.txt
~/Parent/C/100/Folder1/c.txt
```

If i do:

```
find ~/Parent -name "*.txt" | sort -f -r
```

I get

```
~/Parent/C/100/Folder1/c.txt
~/Parent/C/99/Folder1/c.txt
~/Parent/B/13/Folder1/b.txt
~/Parent/B/12/Folder1/b.txt
~/Parent/A/46/Folder1/a.txt
~/Parent/A/45/Folder1/a.txt
```

I want to filter out:

```
~/Parent/C/99/Folder1/c.txt
~/Parent/B/12/Folder1/b.txt
~/Parent/A/45/Folder1/a.txt
```

Comment: In the first example you keep the first file: `A/b.txt` not `B/b.txt`. In the second you keep the last: `100/Folder1/c.txt` not `99/Folder1/c.txt`. Which is right?

Comment: im sorry.  that was confusing.  last is correct, it was clearer when i added the numbers after the letters and removed the mixing of accepted results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the file name with and without its directory, `sort -u` on just the file name, then remove the file name so only the full path shows.

```
$ find ~/Parent -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\t%p\n' | sort -k1,1 -u | cut -f 2-
~/Parent/A/a.txt
~/Parent/A/b.txt
~/Parent/C/c.txt
~/Parent/C/d.txt
```

Note that this will decide conflicts arbitrarily since `find` prints file names in no particular order. If you want to always use the first or the last duplicate files, add an extra `sort` or `sort -r` call:

Always use the first:

```
$ find ~/Parent -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\t%p\n' | sort    | sort -k1,1 -u | cut -f 2-
```

Always use the last:

```
$ find ~/Parent -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\t%p\n' | sort -r | sort -k1,1 -u | cut -f 2-
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the subdirectories are of the same depth, you can do something like this for your example:

```
find -name "*" | sort -t '/' -k3 -u
```

This won't work if there is a subdirectory 'D' within 'C' directory.

Comment: This does solve my example case but I need something that works with more nested subdirectories